# Apache mod_rewrite: how to handle slash in URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a following URL structure:

```
http://mysite.com/movies/index.php?id=123
```

I want to get rid of index.php?id=123 and instead use the following URL:

```
http://mysite.com/movies/123
```

I came up with the following .htaccess in /var/www/mysitecom/movies directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysitecom/movies/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And it works. For example, when I specify ...

```
http://mysite.com/movies/123
```

... I get ...

```
http://mysite.com/movies/index.php?id=123
```

Troubles begin when I specify ...

```
http://mysite.com/movies/123/
```

With this slash, I don't have URL handled properly. It looks like I didn't specify id at all, and all my css styles are not applied.

I tried to play with regular expressions in the rule like ...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)[/]*$ mysitecom/movies/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

... but it didn't help.

So my question is how to handle slash in my case? Should I choose my rewrite rule or need to do something else? I need to ensure that http://mysite.com/movies/123/ handles exactly in the same way as http://mysite.com/movies/123. Any thoughts?

Thanks,

**Update:**

User **DSumsky** helped me (below).

**Dsumsky**, thank you very much for your answer. I decided to comment in the form of the answer to get ability of formatting the text.

First of all, I failed to enable logging. With this strings in my .htaccess ...

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

... I have the following error:

```
Rewrite log not allowed here
```

Well, I placed these strings into /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and restarted apache. The rewrite.log was created, but it gets empty even when rewrite happens.

Second, it didn't work at all without the following strings:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

So I added them. Then, something went wrong with %{HTTP_HOST}, so I changed it a little by specifying a path:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ mysitecom/movies/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Things got better. With both http://mysite.com/movies/123 and http://mysite.com/movies/123/ I see id applied. In the former case everything is completely good, but in the later case css styles are not applied as though they are not specified at all. I don't understand why it happens. For me, it looks like styles are applied BEFORE Rewrite Rule is being executed. I think so because I link styles in the following way:

So, it looks like for /123 it works, I mean Apache is able to find ../library/main.css, but for /123/ it seems to be an embedded directory and ../library/main.css doesn't work.

Any ideas?

**Update2:**

I got it. The final .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RedirectMatch ^(.+[\d+])/$ $1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ mysitecom/movies/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**DSumsky**, thanks for your help! I mark your post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a testing VirtualHost to meet your requirements and configured the following rewrite rule which seems to do what you intended:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/movies/([^/]*)/?$ %{HTTP_HOST}/movies/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The rule matches the last portion of URI which is a kind of movie ID and strips off trailing slash if it's there.

When you are not sure what's going on regarding rewrite engine enable logging as I did configured. You can inspect every singles step the engine performed then and test your rules properly.

I tested it with the following URLs:

```
http://mysite.com/movies/123
http://mysite.com/movies/123/
```

I found the corresponding lines in the log:

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /movies/123
applying pattern '^/movies/([^/]*)/?$' to uri '/movies/123'
rewrite '/movies/123' -> 'mysite.com/movies/index.php?id=123'

init rewrite engine with requested uri /movies/123/
applying pattern '^/movies/([^/]*)/?$' to uri '/movies/123/'
rewrite '/movies/123/' -> 'mysite.com/movies/index.php?id=123'
```

Comment: Dsumsky, thank you very much for your answer. I marked your answer as useful, and it is very useful indeed. I have some kind of progress, but not 100%. I explained the current state below as an answer to keep formatting. Any ideas?

Comment: Update: my post was deleted, so I updated the question above. Thanks!

Comment: Better yet, if you know that `id` must be numeric, then look for `^/movies/(\d*)` — you might as well try to avoid some attack vectors while you rewrite.

Comment: `RewriteLog` option has been deleted in Apache 2.4. Instead append `rewrite:trace3` to `LogLevel`. For example: `LogLevel info rewrite:trace3`